# Как убрать порт 433 из url?

Tags: php, ssl

Метод, формирующий тег canonical, возвращает:

```
return '<link rel="canonical" href="' . ($isHttps ? "https://" : "http://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $uri . '"/>';
```

Однако в html почему-то еще приписывается порт :443

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://site.com:443/catalog/item/"/>
```

Попытка изменить возвращаемое значение метода на

```
return '<link rel="canonical" href="' . ($isHttps ? "https://" : "http://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . str_replace(":443", "", $uri) . '"/>';
```

ничего не дала.

Как можно избавиться от порта в url?

Comment: Так он не в $uri, а в HTTP_HOST

Comment: Спасибо большое